# Could the Higgs boson field be responsible for the dramatic mass increase when an object begins to travel close to the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, higgs

could the Higgs boson field be responsible for the dramatic mass increase incurred when an object nears the speed of light?

Comment: We don't need the Higgs field to explain why an object's **relativistic** mass increases as it approaches the speed of light. This is explained perfectly neatly by Special Relativity.  The Higgs field is needed to account for the **rest** masses of elementary particles.

Comment: @DmitryBrant think the OP was referring to the mechanism of mass increase, which is not explained by relativity. That is, the "how", not "why".

Answer (score 4):

No, it could not.

For one thing, it's not really an object's *mass* that increases as it approaches the speed of light, just its *energy*. This extra energy, namely kinetic energy, has nothing to do with the Higgs mechanism. The Higgs field itself is only responsible for the masses of fundamental particles - in other words, roughly speaking, it gives fundamental particles a certain amount of intrinsic energy which is separate from any kinetic energy they may have.

Comment: It's possibly poor pedagogy, but it's somewhat common to speak of "relativistic mass", as shorthand for the difficulty to accelerate a given object. Of course, this does change with velocity due to contributions from the kinetic energy; it's another way of recognising that momentum scales nonlinearly with velocity. While it is the Higgs field is not required to explain that phenomenon, is it possible to use this as another explanatory mechanism for "relativistic mass", in the same way that Lorentz contraction can be explained without Monkowski space via Poincaré's analysis?

Comment: True, but the reason I didn't mention relativistic mass is that it's kind of an outdated concept; it's often less confusing to just call it energy instead. It's mostly conventional these days that when you say "mass" you mean rest mass, unless otherwise specified. Also, if this is what you were asking at the end: the Higgs field really has no relation to relativistic mass (or energy) whatsoever. They are two entirely different physical mechanisms, you can't use one to explain the other.

Comment: why would kinetic energy prevent acceleration, thus preventing the speed of light from being achieved?  What does the Higgs Field use to create the mass of ordinary particles?

Comment: @joshuaboardman the "distortion" of spacetime that happens as you make something move faster and faster means that acceleration has less of an effect as something approaches the speed of light. As for your second question: would you accept "a vacuum expectation value"? :-P If you're asking about some physical "device" that the Higgs field uses to create mass, it doesn't work that way. The Higgs field itself is the "device," or the closest thing you could get to one.